# selecting cell in tableview while UISearchController is active, doesnt present next view?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uisearchcontroller

I have made a tableview where you can select a cell, and then the viewcontroller will perform a segue to the next view, which works perfectly fine when you are not using the searchcontroller. 
Then when you are using the searchcontroller, it filters the tableview as it should, and the segue is called in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, and the prepareForSegue is called. The problem then is that the view it should segue to is not presented? I can see that the code in the class connected to the view is running, so the segue is performed, it is just the view that does not follow. What am i missing

```
class CompanyListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchResultsUpdating {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

let objectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper()

var activityIndicatorView: SWActivityIndicatorView!

var resultSearchController: UISearchController!

var allCompanies: [Company] = []
var filteredCompanies = [Company]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // set delegates
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    configureSearchController()


    // initialize activity indicator view
    self.activityIndicatorView = SWActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
    activityIndicatorView.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityIndicatorView.color = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
    self.view.addSubview(activityIndicatorView)
    self.activityIndicatorView.center = self.view.center
    activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()

    // fetch all records from backend
    fetchAllRecords({(errors: [NSError]?) -> Void in if errors != nil {print(errors)}})

}

func configureSearchController() {
    // Initialize and perform a minimum configuration to the search controller.
    // Search Bar
    self.resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    self.resultSearchController?.searchBar.autocapitalizationType = .None
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.resultSearchController?.searchBar
    resultSearchController?.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.resultSearchController?.searchResultsUpdater = self
    definesPresentationContext = true

}




// search delegate method
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

        self.filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!)

}


// Filter method, which filters by companyName, and reloads tableview
func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    filteredCompanies = allCompanies.filter { company in
        return company._companyName!.lowercaseString.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)
    }

    tableView.reloadData()
}

// fetch all records from backend
func fetchAllRecords(completionHandler: (errors: [NSError]?) -> Void) {

    let scanExpression = AWSDynamoDBScanExpression()

    objectMapper.scan(Company.self, expression: scanExpression) { (response: AWSDynamoDBPaginatedOutput?, error: NSError?) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            // if error
            if let error = error {
                completionHandler(errors: [error]);
            }
                //if success
            else {
                self.allCompanies = response!.items as! [Company]
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()

            }
        })
    }
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if resultSearchController.active && resultSearchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        return filteredCompanies.count
    }

    return allCompanies.count
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // create a new cell if needed or reuse an old one
    let cell:CompanyListTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("companyCell") as! CompanyListTableViewCell

    // set the text from the data model
    let company:Company?

    if resultSearchController.active && resultSearchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        company = self.filteredCompanies[indexPath.row]


    } else {
        company = self.allCompanies[indexPath.row]
    }

    cell.titleLabel.text = company!._companyName
    cell.imageview?.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")

    return cell
}



func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToProfile", sender: self)

}


// send selected company with segue to profile
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if(segue.identifier == "segueToProfile"){
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

        //tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!, animated: true)

        let selectedRow = indexPath!.row
        let profileVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ProfileViewController

        if resultSearchController.active{

            print(filteredCompanies[selectedRow])
            profileVC.company = filteredCompanies[selectedRow]

        } else {

            profileVC.company = allCompanies[selectedRow]

        }
    }

}
```

}

The console is saying this, but i dont know if that has anything to do with this?

2016-11-26 15:54:07.300 Lostandfound[949:2474251] Warning: Attempt to present   on  which is already presenting

Comment: This is the full console message:

2016-11-26 15:54:07.300 Lostandfound[949:2474251] Warning: Attempt to present <Lostandfound.ProfileViewController: 0x7fe549c6a460>  on <Lostandfound.CompanyListViewController: 0x7fe549e1c3b0> which is already presenting <UISearchController: 0x7fe549e225f0>

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of TableView with  SearchBar control.You should remove didSelectRowAtIndexPath method and use prepareForSegue method for Determine the selected row in TableView.Like this...

Example:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UISearchBarDelegate
{

@IBOutlet weak var SerchBar: UISearchBar!
@IBOutlet weak var TableView: UITableView!


var searchActive : Bool = false
var data = ["San Francisco","New York","San Jose","Chicago","Los Angeles","Austin","Seattle"]
var filtered:[String] = []

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

private func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    if(searchActive)
    {
        return filtered.count
    }
    return data.count;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = self.TableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! TableViewCell
    if(searchActive)
    {
        cell.Label.text = filtered[indexPath.row]
    }
    else
    {
        cell.Label.text = data[indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any!)
{
    if let cell = sender as? TableViewCell
    {
        let i = TableView.indexPath(for: cell)!.row
        if segue.identifier == "segue1"
        {
            if(searchActive)
            {
                let name1 = segue.destination as! SecondView
                name1.str = self.filtered[i]
            }
            else
            {
                let name1 = segue.destination as! SecondView
                name1.str = self.data[i]

            }
        }
    }
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
{
    filtered = data.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
        let tmp: NSString = text as NSString
        let range = tmp.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })
    if(filtered.count == 0)
    {
        searchActive = false;
    }
    else
    {
        searchActive = true;
    }
    self.TableView.reloadData()
}

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
{
    searchActive = true;
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
{
    searchActive = false;
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
{
    searchActive = false;
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar)
{
    searchActive = false;
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

Your SecondView class is:

```
import UIKit

class SecondView: UIViewController
{
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
var str:String!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.label.text = str
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

}
```

And your TableViewCell is:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
@IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
override func awakeFromNib()
{
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
{
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

}

}
```